# Checking on the legality of a move

Tags: illegal-move

[image]I moved my white King to d4, taking black's bishop. This put the king in a checkmate with black's knight on c6. Is this move legal or illegal? Thank you.

Comment: Put a diagram of your position, to understand the situation.

Comment: Did you mean "This put the king in check" ? Because checkmate is a different concept.

Comment: That image needs to be rotated 90 degrees clockwise. Better yet, use [FEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation) to enter it as a diagram. See this [meta post](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247/instructions-to-post-a-game-in-the-help-faq-or-even-wysiwig-editor) for more details.

Comment: Sorry all I am not very proficient when posting...my first time.

Answer (score 3):

Kd4 is not a legal move. You are never allowed to put yourself into a check.

Even though it's possible to argue "black's knight can't take my king as that would put his king in check", it's still not legal. You can imagine that if the game could continue, black would capture the white king before white could capture the black king, and black would therefore win. This is of course just a device for explaining the why, as capturing a king is just as much an illegal move as putting your own king in check.